# Binary recurrence sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, diophantine-approximation

> Let $u_n=Au_{n-1}+Bu_{n-2}$ binary recurrence sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ and the companion polynomial $x^2-Ax-B$ has distinct zeros $\alpha,\beta$. Then for all $n \geq 0$
>   $$u_n= \gamma_1 \alpha^n + \gamma_2 \beta^n$$ 
>   for some $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$. Assume that $A^2+4B^2 >0$, i.e., $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $\alpha \neq \pm \beta$. Assume further that we have $\gamma_1\gamma_2 \neq 0$. Prove that there are effectively computable numbers $c>0$, $n_0$ such that
>   $$|u_n| \geq c \max(|\alpha|,|\beta|)^n$$ 
>   for $n \geq n_0$.

Assume $|\beta|=\max(|\alpha|,|\beta|) >0 $ then
$$|u_n|=|\gamma_1\alpha^n + \gamma_2 \beta^n|=|\beta|^n\cdot|\gamma_1\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^n+\gamma_2|$$
However, I cannot indicate the term $|\gamma_1\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^n+\gamma_2| >c$ for some constant $c>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $ \left |\left (\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \right )^n\right | \to _{n\to \infty} 0$, and therefore you can make it as small as you want for large values of $n$, and you can get as closer as you want to $|\gamma_2|$ (which is positive).

Comment: In your assumption, you have $|\beta|=\max(|\alpha|,|\beta|) $, so it is true that $\left | \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\right|\leq 1$ and hence $\left | \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \right |^n\to 0$ and so $\left |\left (\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \right )^n\right | \to _{n\to \infty} 0$. Hope it's clear now. You will need to formalize that into a proof

Comment: Oh you're right. So stupid question. Thanks!